# Are the properties of i, j, and x, y in the following program same?

Tags: c

I think that the C programming language should be more clear with regards to syntax for certain elements.

I have tried to solve this with an emulator but it was to slow.

```
typedef unsigned long into uli;
uli i, j;
unsigned long int x, y;
```

Comment: Add `c` as language tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are. The C programming language contains various discrepancies but this question is relatively simple. The terms "uli" and "unsigned long int" are the exact same thing.